# authentication best practice and server vs client rendering

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication

Note: I'm doing some projects as portfolio to get into junior web dev. So I want to know what's the best practice in the "real world"

1. Is my authentication in good practice?:

People can create accounts (has google antibot and jquery validation), then in server (built a restful api with slim, php) it will store a salt and hashed pw in database. Server will create token for user with 3 hrs expiration. Token is stored in client's sessionStorage. Each time client talk to server it'll give userid and token on a SSL connection

People can use facebook login too, it goes as follows:

- client -> facebook
- facebook give userid and token to client
- client sent them to my server using ajax (SSL)
- server check with facebook confirm it is a legit user
- server create token for user. token work the same as normal user

-

2. Second question is regarding php. So far everything I'm doing is through ajax. when Client (html and javascript) need resources/data, it will make a request to the restful api (php), my backend api does nothing but send data to client through ajax, it doesn't do any rendering or javascript. However I see a lot of website where I go on it and I'm browsing a php file. I have watched video and tutorial articles and a lot of them render javascript from php. I just dont see the point of doing that, am I misunderstanding something very fundamental? Because of this I don't even understand why we need MVC for backend. I honestly have did my research but cannot find the answer

Im just not sure if Im following the best practices, and if Im following the similar protocol as people in the workplaces.

Comment: The part with rendering js from PHP is more or less, by my understanding, a trade-off choice. You can either have a longer page load time for the index and load most JS there, and ajax content will load faster, or you can have the index load faster, and javascript that's only loaded when needed. Also, an interesting usage of loading JS from PHP is that you can re-declare old junk functions or variables saving memory and more.

Comment: Another comment to separate the last part and give an example, I have two different pages that each have their own intervals and other crap. I load all my pages with jquery, and I noticed that even after changing pages, the intervals keep running. But in every different page I can declare a `function clearStuff()` that removes whatever that particular page loaded, and then before loading the next page, I can just call `clearStuff()`, without needing to hard-code the calls for each page.

Comment: oh ok so it is a 'it depends' kinda thing. Thanks! now I know which direction to look to determine which to use

Comment: I don't exactly have work experience so I can't tell you which one to choose, but if any of the choices were ***bad*** I'd expect to find a lot of articles about it. My best bet would be being able to explain the consequences of each method, because after all it will be up to the client.